# Getting Value error: Shape of passed values is (14, 78692), indices imply (14, 78250)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using concat operation on two data-frame. But I am getting the value error: Shape of passed values is (14, 78692), indices imply (14, 78250)
The dataframes has properties:
[9935 rows x 6 columns] and [68316 rows x 8 columns]
If we add both the rows we get 78250, but not sure why its giving this error.

```
    final_df = pd.concat([df, tp_df],axis=1)
```

I have two other sets of data as well with same columns and different number of rows and its working fine on that data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without you sample data, I just make a guess. Normally, `pd.concat` on `axis=1` fails when there is duplicates index in either or both dataframe. Try to run these:

```
df.index.duplicated().any()
```

and

```
tp_df.index.duplicated().any()
```

If either or both return `True` and you want to retain the current index of `df` and `tp_df`, you need outer join as follows

```
df.join(tp_df, how='outer')
```

If you don't want retain current index, just do as follows:

```
pd.concat([df.reset_index(drop=True), tp_df.reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
```

**Note**: `pd.concat` with `reset_index` will line-up rows and  columns different than outer join, so it depends on your desired output and choose accordingly.